# Convert to NSData to Bytes

Tags: iphone

I want to convert the NSData to bytes array.
I have one webservice to which I want to pass this bytes array.

How can i do?

Thanks you

Answer (score 4):

Look into using the [`bytes`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIAEAJGI), [`getBytes:length:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIACCIAJ), or [`getBytes:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIACCFDG) methods of NSData (each of those is a link to the documentation).

Answer (score 3):

```
char * bytes = [SomeData bytes];
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there is a `bytes` method that will give you a pointer to the raw data and a `getBytes:length:` method that will copy the data into given buffer.